# Trigger on PricebookEntry

Tags: trigger, pricebookentry

I want a field on Custom PriceBookEntry to be updated from Standard PriceBookEntry when it is created. However, Salesforce doesn't allow writing a trigger on PricebookEntry. What are the options I am left with? Scheduled Apex is one I can think but it is not realtime.

Comment: you may want to use batch process

Comment: Thats what we used in the end. However, we wanted it to be realtime but sadly it was not possible.